# need help on java programming

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary

I have a homework and after struggling a lot i didn't succeed to solve it so i ask it here , the question is : we have list of students and their grades in a string.the string contain Student number , Name , LastName, courseName , Grade , and then split with ";" and then another records of student so the string is like this:

> 75414133,Mehdi,Javan,Math,16;
> 88887777,Shadi,Khani,English,18;
> 75414133,Mehdi,Javan,English,12;
> 88887777,Shadi,Khani,Physiques,16;
> 512345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Chemistry,15;
> 88887777,Shadi,Khani,Math,15;

We need a java program to calculate the average of grade and write down the name of the class with their grades (grade must be in ascending order). We must use List and map to implement this code. the out put should be like this :

> 75414133,Mehdi,Javan:
>
> ```
> Average: 14
>
> English: 12
>
> Math: 16
> ```
>
> 88887777,Shadi,Khani:
>
> ```
> Average: 16.5
>
> Math: 15
>
> Physiques: 16.5
>
> English: 18
> ```

Sorry guys i do my best. But i didn't succeed to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Edit : here is uncompleted code i had written , it's wrong but since i was asked for to write it here by some user i wrote my wrong code here :

```
public class Average
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str ="75414133,Mehdi,Javan,Math,16;88887777,Shadi,Khani,English,18;12345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Chemistry,15;75414133,Mehdi,Javan,English,12;88887777,Shadi,Khani,Math,15;88887777,Shadi,Khani,Physiques,16.5;12345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Sport,17.25;75414133,Mehdi,Javan,English,12;12345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Islamic Revolution,8";
        String[] strRecords = str.split(";");

        for(int i=0;i<strRecords.length;i++){
            String[] strColon= strRecords[i].split(",");

            for (int j=1;j<strRecords.length;j++){
                if(Integer.valueOf(strRecords[i].substring(0,8)) ==Integer.valueOf(strRecords[j].substring(0,8)) ){
                    String strName = strColon[0] + "," + strColon[1]+"," +strColon[2];
                    System.out.println(strName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must show code in order for us to help you otherwise we are flying blind.  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: ok ,  i Would edit the first post and write the code i tried (though) it's not written in good shape and is wrong, but i will.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Also, what is wrong with your code? In what way isn't it doing what you want?

Comment: This homework was first designed by me in my Java class in 2013 in Pooya Company :) So, I thought it's worth posting another more complete answer for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you want

```
public class StudentMain
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JAXBException
    {
        String input = "75414133,Mehdi,Javan,Math,16; 88887777,Shadi,Khani,English,18; 75414133,Mehdi,Javan,English,12; 88887777,Shadi,Khani,Physiques,16; 512345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Chemistry,15; 88887777,Shadi,Khani,Math,15;";

        String[] studentRecords = input.split(";");

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for (String studentRecord : studentRecords)
        {
            String[] studentData = studentRecord.split(",");

            Student student = new Student(studentData[0], studentData[1], studentData[2]);

            if (students.contains(student))
            {
                student = students.get(students.indexOf(student));

                student.addScore(studentData[3], Integer.valueOf(studentData[4]));
            }
            else
            {
                student.addScore(studentData[3], Integer.valueOf(studentData[4]));                
                students.add(student);
            }
        }

        for (Student student : students)
        {
            student.printScoreCard();
        }
    }
}

class Student
{
    private String number;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Map<String, Integer> scores = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public Student(String number, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.number = number.trim();
        this.firstName = firstName.trim();
        this.lastName = lastName.trim();
    }

    public void addScore(String subject, Integer score)
    {
        this.scores.put(subject, score);
    }

    public void printScoreCard()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(number + "," + firstName + "," + lastName + ":");
        System.out.println("Average: " + getAverageScore());

        for (Entry<String, Integer> score : scores.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(score.getKey() + ": " + score.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    private double getAverageScore()
    {
        double average = 0.0;

        for (Entry<String, Integer> score : scores.entrySet())
        {
            average = average + score.getValue();
        }

        average = average / scores.size();
        return average;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Student))
        {
            return false;
        }

        Student compareTo = (Student) o;

        return number.equals(compareTo.number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse you string using String.split() method.Like
 `yourString.split(":")` to separate all students. Then you can do string.split(",") to extract all the attributes of each student. Than you can make a Student class and make objects with essential attributes.

Comment: Thanks for respond , but the code should be splitted by ";" not ":" you mentioned . would u please write your meaning with programming language , i need help for implementing map and list which in question is asked for , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although Sanket's answer is quiet OK, I'd like to post another answer with higher performance. Some notable points are:

- The order of the algorithm must be O(n) so instead of using an `ArrayList` to store Students a `HashMap` is used because `contains` method of `ArrayList` uses a loop to find the object and its order is O(n) while order of finding an entry by its key in `HashMap` is O(1).
- Collection capacity should be initialized. It affects performance when we deal with large number of objects.
- For solving this problem, it is not necessary to use a `Map` to store scores' data and a simple `List` is sufficient.

Here is the answer:

Main class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "75414133,Mehdi,Javan,Math,16;88887777,Shadi,Khani,English,18;12345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Chemistry,15;75414133,Mehdi,Javan,English,12; 88887777,Shadi,Khani,Math,15;88887777,Shadi,Khani,Physiques,16.5;12345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Sport,17.25;12345678,Mohamad,Sayadi,Islamic Revolution,8";

        String[] studentRecords = input.split(";");
        Map<Long, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>(studentRecords.length);
        for (String record : studentRecords) {
            String[] fields = record.split(",");
            Long id = Long.valueOf(fields[0].trim());
            String firstName = fields[1];
            String lastName = fields[2];

            Student student = studentMap.get(id);
            if (student == null) {
                student = new Student(id, firstName, lastName);
                studentMap.put(id, student);
            }

            String courseTitle = fields[3];
            Float score = Float.valueOf(fields[4]);
            student.getCourseList().add(new Course(courseTitle, score));
        }

        for (Student student : studentMap.values())
            student.printInfo();
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Student(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourseList() {
        return courseList;
    }

    public void setCourseList(List<Course> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(id + "," + firstName + "," + lastName);
        System.out.println(String.format("Average: %.2f", calculateAverage()));

        for (Course course : courseList)
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: %.2f", course.getTitle(), course.getScore()));
    }

    private float calculateAverage() {
        float sum = 0;

        for (Course course : courseList)
            sum += course.getScore();

        float average = sum / (float) courseList.size();

        return average;
    }
}
```

Course class:

```
public class Course {
    private String title;
    private Float score;

    public Course(String title, Float score) {
        this.title = title;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Float getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Float score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```